# How to send Taleo connect client(TCC) export file to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, configuration, export, cloud, tcc

I was working in TCC in Windows 10, with Recruiting 17.4 requisition export. I  am able to see the files in location.

I wanted to upload/send files directly to S3 bucket. Is there any option in TCC software or TCC Cloud for the same. I don't to use use any sFTP location.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way:

1. Add a step in Post processing step
2. Choose "Add a custom step" From
3. Steps drop down, choose "FTP Put"
4. Provide host port configuration details of the FTP location
5. Run the configuration

But I am yet to discover how S3 upload can be done in sFTP mode, found an article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-amazon-s3/